# How to use a singleton class as a replacement for ENUM in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class called "Card" that contains "Sides".

Both entities have a Stage - one of three stages.

Here's my **Card** entity:

```
public class Card
{
    public Card()
    {
        Sides = new Collection<Side>();
        Stage = Stage.ONE;
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public virtual int CardId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CardId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Side> Sides { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my **Side** entity:

```
public class Side
{
    public Side()
    {
        Stage = Stage.ONE;
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]     
    public virtual int SideId { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CardId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CardId")]
    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }

}
```

And here's my **Stage** entity:

```
public class Stage
{
    // Zero
    public static readonly Stage ONE = new Stage(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), "ONE");
    // Ten seconds
    public static readonly Stage TWO = new Stage(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10), "TWO");

    public static IEnumerable<Stage> Values
    {
        get
        {
            yield return ONE;
            yield return TWO;
        }

    }

    public int StageId { get; set; }
    private readonly TimeSpan span;
    public string Title { get; set; }

    Stage(TimeSpan span, string title)
    {
        this.span = span;
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public TimeSpan Span { get { return span; } }
}
```

I noticed that when I create a new Card or Side, the Stage table gets a new entry with a Title of "ONE" and an auto-incremented ID - this should not be happening.  There should only ever be Two stages in the Stage table.  A Stage is basically an enum with some values - Title, and Span.

How can I prevent new Stages from being added?  I'm using EF CodeFirst in case it's relevant.

**UPDATE based on Honza's response:**

```
public class Stage
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int StageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Span { get; set; }

    public static class Values
    {
        public static readonly Stage ONE = new Stage()
            {
                StageId = 0,
                Name = "ONE",
                Span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
            };
        public static readonly Stage TWO = new Stage()
        {
            StageId = 1,
            Name = "TWO",
            Span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)
        };
    }
```

It's still auto-incrementing though - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you instantiate `ONE` and `TWO`, they get created without a `StageId`. Entity Framework needs a hint to be able to tell that they are equal to already existing Stage entries. Make `StageId` the key and **specify it when creating those instances**. That way EF can tell they are already in the DB and references the existing ones instead of creating new ones.

It is a very "hardcoded" approach though.

It may be better, instead of creating instances this way, to look for them in the DB (based on the Title I'd guess) and create them if they aren't there. Such operation may not be suitable for static field initialization though, because it you for example get an SQL timeout exception (DB may be on another machine, network may hiccup...), the whole type will not be able to load and that's a messy situation to deal with.

Instead of the static fields, you can just hold the instances in the object that uses the Stages. This would make the DB-related jobs and error handlind easier and would allow for better testability (you could use whatever instances as `ONE` and `TWO`, not the hardcoded ones).

Comment: Thanks Honza.  I just added [Key] to StageId and specified the Ids, however it's still happening.  I'll update my post with the new code now.  Any idea what else I might need to do?

Comment: Is the change reflected in the DB itself? I haven't worked with code-first that much.

Comment: It seems so... I just ran the migration again and I can see the changes.  I created three new Cards and see three instances of Stage One though :/

Comment: Maybe EF needs another hint in decorating the `Card.Stage` property with `ForeignKey("StageId")` attribute. I'm merely guessing here though, can't try it myself now, sorry.